# Ubuntu 14.04 second monitor with nvidia gpu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, monitor, lts

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 On my system, but can't get the second monitor to work. Right after the installation, the monitor was working, as I was using the standard nouveau driver, but this driver made my system freeze after some seconds, so I changed to the newest nvidia driver under additional drivers (binary driver version 346.96). With the nvidia driver I could only boot with nomodeset, and with this flag two screens wouldn't work, so I tried to work around it. I found out in another thread, that I should disable my integrated GPU, which I did with

`echo "blacklist i915" | sudo tee --append /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Now I can boot into my installation without problems, but my second monitor still doesn't work. Can anyone help me with this? I had the same problem under 15.04 which I installed two days ago. Didn't find a solution, so I thought I might have more luck with 14.04, but things are still the same. Thanks in advance

Edit: Oh yeah, forgot to mention that my gpu is the nvidia geforce gtx660 and my cpu is an intel 3570k